# Vim change filetype after typing shebang line

Tags: vim, file-type

I want Vim to change the `filetype` when I type a shebang line (eg. `#!/bin/bash`) on the first line of a new buffer.

Currently I'm using `vim-shebang` plugin for changing filetype, but it only works when opening a new buffer.

**Clarification:** I'm interested in achieving the desired result by mapping `<CR>` in insert mode. What I want is when I type `#!/bin/bash<CR>` on the first line of a buffer to automatically execute `:filetype detect` and return to editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to [read the (always great) documentation of Vim](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#new-filetype-scripts) (which I'm quoting bellow):

```
:help new-filetype-scripts
```

This might help you.

> If your filetype can only be detected by inspecting the contents of
>   the    file.
>
> 1. Create your user runtime directory.  You would normally use the first
>        item of the `'runtimepath'` option.  Example for Unix: `:!mkdir ~/.vim`
> 2. Create a vim script file for doing this.  Example:
>
>    ```
>     if did_filetype()    " filetype already set..
>       finish     " ..don't do these checks
>     endif
>     if getline(1) =~ '^#!.*\<mine\>'
>       setfiletype mine
>     elseif getline(1) =~? '\<drawing\>'
>       setfiletype drawing
>     endif
>    ```
>
>    See `$VIMRUNTIME/scripts.vim` for more examples.
>
>    Write this file as "scripts.vim" in your user runtime directory.  For
>       example, for Unix:
>
>    ```
>     :w ~/.vim/scripts.vim
>    ```

*Update* (after the edit of the original question): I'd recommend against the mapping of , but you can do it with

```
:inoremap <CR> YOUR_SPECIAL_FUNCTION_WHICH_DETECS_THE_CURRENT_LINE_AND_RUNS_FILETYPE_DETECT
```

The above code snippet (`if getline(1)`... is enough to get you started. We are not the writethecodeformeforfree.com community.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
:filetype detect
```

to re-trigger the filetype detection after you've written the shebang line.

This can be automated with `:autocmd`, e.g. on the `BufWritePost` when `&filetype` is still empty.